# C++ STL set with custom comparator

Tags: stl, set, comparator

For a C++ STL `set` I need a custom compare, but there is something seriously wrong with my code. Using Visual Studio 2019, it fails to compile. The first error is (in xutility) "error C2672: 'operator __surrogate_func': no matching overloaded function found".

Here is the code:

```
#include <set>

struct P
{
    char a;
    char b;
    char c;
};

class PSortingCriterion
{
public:
    bool operator() (const P &p1, const P &p2) const
    {
        if(p1.a != p2.a)
            return p1.a < p2.a;
        else if(p1.b != p2.b)
            return p1.b < p2.b;
        else if(p1.c != p2.c)
            return p1.c < p2.c;
        else
            return false; // p1 == p2
    }
};

std::set<P, PSortingCriterion> s1, s2, diff;

void F(void)
{
    if(s1 != s2) // errors are all due to this statement; no errors if it's removed
    {
    }
}
```

Update: Following Igor Tandetnik's suggestion, I have modified the code, but it still doesn't compile (same error as above).

New code:

```
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

struct P
{
    char a;
    char b;
    char c;
};

class PSortingCriterion
{
public:
    bool operator() (const P &p1, const P &p2) const
    {
        if(p1.a != p2.a)
            return p1.a < p2.a;
        else if(p1.b != p2.b)
            return p1.b < p2.b;
        else if(p1.c != p2.c)
            return p1.c < p2.c;
        else
            return false; // p1 == p2
    }
};

std::set<P, PSortingCriterion> s1, s2, diff;

void F(void)
{
    set_difference(s1.begin(), s1.end(), s2.begin(), s2.end(), inserter(diff, diff.begin()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To compare two sets, you compare the elements. See [CppReference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/operator_cmp). But you haven't provided any way of comparing two objects of type `P` for equality.

if you add:

```
bool operator== (const P& p1, const P& p2) {
   return p1.a == p2.a && p1.b == p2.b && p1.c == p2.c;
}
```

Then your code will compile.

Comment: Your suggestion does work (thank you), but it doesn't do what I need. I need to be able to use `set_difference`. If I add the line `if(s1<s2)`, I get the errors I originally showed, in spite of the fact that I provided a functor to do the comparison.

Comment: @Woody20 `set<T, Compare>::operator<` is documented to ignore `Compare`, and use less-than `<` operator for comparing the sets' elements. But you haven't provided one. If you want to use `set_difference`, then by all means use it - call the overload that takes a comparator as an argument.

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik I tried your suggestion, but there is still something wrong. I have posted the complete code as an addition to the original question.

Comment: Which part of "use overload of `set_difference` that takes a comparator" was unclear? Make it `set_difference(s1.begin(), s1.end(), s2.begin(), s2.end(), inserter(diff, diff.begin()), PSortingCriterion{});`

Comment: I am following the example in Josuttis' book, 10.1.1 Function Objects as Sorting Criteria, where he says the sort criterion defined as I have done is a type, and can be used as a template argument for the set. I assumed this meant that when I defined `P`, `PSortingCriterion`, which defines `<`, would be used as the default.

Comment: Changing to `std::set<P> s1, s2, diff;` and `set_difference(s1.begin(), s1.end(), s2.begin(), s2.end(), inserter(diff, diff.begin()), PSortingCriterion{});` gives the error "binary '<': 'const _Ty' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator". I added a definition of `operator<` in `struct P`, and now it compiles. But what I really want is a `set` with a built-in default ordering to be used for `<`, sorting, and merge algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example of overloading `==` and `!=` operators (which is what you're trying to do I think?)

```cpp
#include<set>
#include<iostream>

struct P {
    char a;
    char b;
    char c;
    bool operator==(const P &p2) const {
      return this->a == p2.a && this->b == p2.b && this->c == p2.c;
    }
    bool operator!=(const P &p2) const {
      return this->a != p2.a || this->b != p2.b || this->c != p2.c;
    }
};

void EqualExample(void) {
  P s1;
  s1.a = 'a';
  s1.b = 'b';
  s1.c = 'c';
  P s2;
  s2.a = 'a';
  s2.b = 'b';
  s2.c = 'c';
  if(s1 != s2){
    std::cout << "Not Equal" << std::endl;
  } else {
    std::cout << "Equal" << std::endl;
  }
}

void NotEqualExample(void) {
  P s1;
  s1.a = 'a';
  s1.b = 'b';
  s1.c = 'c';
  P s2;
  s2.a = 'a';
  s2.b = 'b';
  s2.c = 'd';
  if(s1 != s2){
    std::cout << "Not Equal" << std::endl;
  } else {
    std::cout << "Equal" << std::endl;
  }
}

int main () {
  EqualExample();
  NotEqualExample();
}
```

Comment: You can get rid of the `iostream` include if you don't need it for anything else I'm just using it for the print

Comment: See my response to Marshall Chow.